# On which site should I ask for criticism on my CPU design and ISA?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to know how I can improve my instruction set and hypothetical CPU design. Which, if any, Stack Exchange sites would be suited to this?

My first guess would be [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but that seems to be for software only and not hypothetical hardware designs.

Comment: Computer Science? https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Glorfindel that does look promising. I'll have a look at the help page.

Comment: @Glorfindel the only problem I can see is that my question is more 'open ended' and cs stackexchange doesn't seem the place to ask that kind of question

Comment: @Jachdich As you correctly identified, "Please review my CPU design" is a very open-ended question and perhaps not a good fit with SE in general.

Comment: @MechMK1 Isn't codereview "please review my software"?

Comment: @Jachdich Code Review is an exception, just like Puzzling, Code Golf and some others. I can't tell if Code Review would consider a CPU architecture as "code" though.

Comment: If you want, ask on the CodeReview Meta if it would be okay to post this for review. I'm a regular there, but even I am not sure how it would go.

Comment: @IEatBagels Alright I'll post something there shortly

Comment: EE is definitely the best place if you want feedback from people with HDL language experience etc. Doubt you'll find many of those at Code Review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Electical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) [accepts design reviews](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/requests-for-review-on-topic) under some conditions, and [CPU design](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew-cpu?tab=Newest) 
 and [instruction set](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instruction-set?tab=Newest) matters are on-topic there.

However, you must take care that the question is not too broad, but this is probably the case for all sites on which it would be on-topic. So, try to narrow the question down as much as possible, and focus on the choices you're not sure about. You could even break this in multiple questions, one for each specific concern you have on your design.

You can't post your entire specs and just ask "what do you think about all this?".